# Android - Add Accessibility to the Menu Button

Tags: android, menu, accessibility

I need to add accessibility to the menu button (physical menu button or non)  How can I add accessibility to this component?

Something in here?

public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
        onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
    }

Thanks!

Comment: "I need to add accessibility to the menu button" -- what does this mean? I can see worrying about accessibility on the action bar items (those in the bar itself and those in the overflow), but that should happen automatically when you supply `android:title` on the `<item>` elements in your menu resource.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Basically, when someone clicks the menu button currently it says 'displaying 3 items' ... I need it to say something like 'The menu button will allow you to access addiitonal features' or some such thing.  So it's literally on touching the menu button

Comment: I would think that users relying upon accessibility would be used to the existing message. More importantly, the existing message delivers information that they may need (i.e., how many items there are). Why do you think that changing the message is in the best interests of your accessibility-enabled users?

Comment: Well it needs to say "More options, Open drop-down list of more options" to be more descriptive.

Comment: I'd **uninstall** an app which **bores me** every time I'd touch the menu button by telling me what I already know (it's useless to tell the user that a menu behaves like a menu)!

Comment: It's for people with low vision thus accessibility.  A regular user would not use it

Comment: If you're using standard Android menus, you should expect users to be familiar with what a menu is and how to interact with it. There is no need for a verbose description.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by CommonsWare in the comments you just have to setTitle on your MenuItem entries. For example during inflation like:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
     menu.getItem(0).setTitle(R.string.first_label_for_menu_item);
     menu.getItem(1).setTitle(R.string.second_label_for_menu_item);
}
```